# SSIS Script Component File Location

Tags: ssis

I am trying to commit my SSIS package to Git and I'm running into an issue with adding the Script Component code files.  I have my SSIS package within my Git repository location, but the code file is located in the AppData folder as such:

> C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\SSIS_SC110\Vstak5QLNZovpE__2Hp8ieeyROw\Vsta_luuBHnd9ka0dNruaTdUoQ\main.cs

I would like to add the entire SSIS package to Git so others can use the SSIS package on the team. Does anyone know how to add the "Script Component" files to the repository?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Where is the local git repository? What developing environment do you use? How did you create/add your SISS package? (I'm guessing as well that you use C#, so you might want to tag it so)

Comment: When you're editing the script, it's in the temporary location. However, once you exit the script editor, it's serialized and added as a resource inside the .dtsx file. You commit the dtsx file and when the next person gets the package from the repository, the script will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the usual behavior of the Visual Studio. When you open up a script task it will be added to a temporary location. while opening it will go to a temporary location to edit.

Once you clean and build the application it will be available inside of the .dtsx package. You have to commit the entire project and for a new user who get a pull will get the code without any issue.